# Convert Heroes of the Storm replay file (.StormReplay) to any video format

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Is it possible to convert `.StormReplay` files to anything like `.mp4` or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only by loading the replay in heroes of the storm and then recording that footage.

Replays in games aren't videos, they're a list of "At point N in time, X happened to unit Y", watching a replay is then replaying all of the actions, one after another and displaying the results.

Comment: As I suspected :( Well, at least we can load the replay and record...